# AWS Says Simple Email Service is not available in this region,How to fix this?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Please help me to fix this region unsupported error:

> **Simple Email Service** is not available in **Asia Pacific (Mumbai)**. Please select another region.

[image: Error]

Comment: You can't fix this, this  means that amazon does not provide this in your region.
We can however,  try to  find a workaround if you explain what you're trying  to  achieve.

Comment: If `SES` is not available, then you can change the `region` at the top right corner of the console and setup SES in another region. Please be aware that the charges might be different and if there are any business policies that don't allow usage of other regions.

Comment: Actually, you still can use other regine's SES.

Answer (score 1):

Not all AWS services are available in every region. A list of services available in each region can be found in: [Region Table](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/?p=gi)

If you service you seek is not available in a particular region, you can still use the service in another region.

While many AWS users wish to keep their data in a particular region for **data governance** purposes, Amazon SES is used to send emails to the Internet so it does not really need to fit this data governance model (the email is being sent outside of the region anyway).

If you are having a particular problem using the service from another region, please post a Question with the specific problem you are facing.